# Add a Table Column dynamically using checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following is my source code

I need to add table column dynamically using checkbox in javascript and if I uncheck the checkbox, it needs to be disable the particular column in table and if I again click the same checkbox, the column should appear at same location so please help me to rectify the problem....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>1.Table</title>
    <style>
    #Whole-Wrapper
    {
        background:gray;
        height:700px;
    }

    h1{text-align:center;}

    table,th,td
    {
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }

    td{padding:10px;}

    #Wrapper
    {
        width:90%;
        margin:10% auto;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    #div1
    {
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        background:lightblue;
    }


    #div2
    {
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        background:lightyellow;
        height:256px;
    }

    #ClearFix
    {
        clear:both;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Whole-Wrapper">
<h1>Create Table Using Checkbox</h1>
    <div id="Wrapper">

        <div id="div1">
            <h2>First Column</h2>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onclick="myFunction(1)"><label>First Checkbox</label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onclick="myFunction(2)"><label>Second Checkbox</label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" onclick="myFunction(3)"><label>Third Checkbox</label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" onclick="myFunction(4)"><label>Fourth Checkbox</label><br><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" onclick="myFunction(5)"><label>Fifth Checkbox</label><br><br>
        </div>

        <div id="div2">
            <h2>Second Column</h2>
            <table id="mtTbl">
                <tr id="Head"></tr>

                <tr id="Tr1"></tr>

                <tr id="Tr2"></tr>

                <tr id="Tr3"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="ClearFix"></div>
    </div>
</div>  
    <script>
    function myFunction(cellNo)
    {
        var a = document.getElementById("chk"+cellNo);

        if(a.checked)
        {
            var x = document.createElement("TH");
            var y = document.createTextNode("Table Header"+cellNo);
            x.appendChild(y);
            document.getElementById("Head").appendChild(x);

            var x1 = document.createElement("TD");
            var y1 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
            x1.appendChild(y1);
            document.getElementById("Tr1").appendChild(x1);

            var x2 = document.createElement("TD");
            var y2 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
            x2.appendChild(y2);
            document.getElementById("Tr2").appendChild(x2);

            var x3 = document.createElement("TD");
            var y3 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
            x3.appendChild(y3);
            document.getElementById("Tr3").appendChild(x3);
        }
        else 
        {
            var delHead = document.getElementById("Head");
            delHead.deleteCell(cellNo-1);

            var col1 = document.getElementById("Tr1");
            col1.deleteCell(cellNo-1);

            var col2 = document.getElementById("Tr2");
            col2.deleteCell(cellNo-1);

            var col3 = document.getElementById("Tr3");
            col3.deleteCell(cellNo-1);


            /*var delHead = document.getElementById("Head");
            delHead.deleteCell(cellNo-cellNo);

            var col1 = document.getElementById("Tr1");
            col1.deleteCell(cellNo-cellNo);

            var col2 = document.getElementById("Tr2");
            col2.deleteCell(cellNo-cellNo);

            var col3 = document.getElementById("Tr3");
            col3.deleteCell(cellNo-cellNo);

            var col4 = document.getElementById("Tr4");
            col4.deleteCell(cellNo-cellNo)

            var b = document.getElementById("Head");
            b.style.display = "chk"+cellNo.checked ? "block" : "none";

            var c = document.getElementById("Tr1");
            c.style.display = "chk"+cellNo.checked ? "block" : "none";

            var d = document.getElementById("Tr2");
            d.style.display = "chk"+cellNo.checked ? "block" : "none";

            var e = document.getElementById("Tr3");
            e.style.display = "chk"+cellNo.checked ? "block" : "none";*/
            }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by disable a column?

Comment: disable a column means hide a column

Comment: do you want to consider jquery?

Answer (score 0):

i have created one codepen for you with javascript example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyQZyw

script just changed as below.

```
function myFunction(cellNo)
{
    var a = document.getElementById("chk"+cellNo);

    if(a.checked)
    {
        var x = document.createElement("TH");
        var y = document.createTextNode("Table Header"+cellNo);
        x.appendChild(y);
       x.id = "th"+cellNo; document.getElementById("Head").appendChild(x);

        var x1 = document.createElement("TD");
        var y1 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
        x1.appendChild(y1);
       x1.id = "Tr1td"+cellNo; document.getElementById("Tr1").appendChild(x1);

        var x2 = document.createElement("TD");
        var y2 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
        x2.appendChild(y2);
       x2.id = "Tr2td"+cellNo; document.getElementById("Tr2").appendChild(x2);

        var x3 = document.createElement("TD");
        var y3 = document.createTextNode("Row"+cellNo);
        x3.appendChild(y3);
       x3.id = "Tr3td"+cellNo; document.getElementById("Tr3").appendChild(x3);
    }
    else 
    {            
        document.getElementById("th"+cellNo).remove();
      document.getElementById("Tr1td"+cellNo).remove();
      document.getElementById("Tr2td"+cellNo).remove();
      document.getElementById("Tr3td"+cellNo).remove();
        }
}
```

Comment: ya it will be working good when i click all the checkbox and what is my problem is if i unclick the second checkbox the checkbox was deleted and again if i click the same checkbox means it will create at the end of the table ,So my concept is if again click the checkbox means it will show again at its 2nd position without changing so please help me

Comment: are you comfortable whit jqeury or you want JavaScript only?

Comment: i need only in javascript only because javascript was only my requirement